# Access ('07 -'10) form is not showing entered records

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that I enter data into that is broken into a number of different tables for normalization.

However, once I reopen the form, only the first record is shown.
I have it set as "single form" and Data Entry is set to "no".
I've tried some macros to open the form to the last record but those don't seem to work.

Comment: [I think I've found them](http://www.whbc963hd3.com/welcomehome/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/records.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to continuous forms instead of single.

Also, if it's set to single form you should be able to navigate thorough all the records, one at time, with the navigation buttons in the lower left of the form.

Comment: Thanks, Pappy, for some reason it's only recognizing the first record.  
I'm testing it with 20 records and the navigation button in the bottom only shows one record. When I navigate to the next record it opens a new record.